# Лучше использовать props или vuex?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, frontend

В проекте подключён vue и vuex.

*Понятно что есть ситуации в которых без vuex не обойтись.Но часто возникают спорные ситуации(компоненты находятся в иерархии), когда не понятно как работать через с данными, через props или через vuex...*

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие нибудь принципы, когда для передачи лучше использовать props(и другие механизмы vue), а когда лучше использовать store в vuex?**

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите vuexok https://spb-web.github.io/vuexok/ Упрощает вызов экшенов и мутаций, и упрощает передачу данных из стора в компоненты

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в проекте есть контейнеры (компоненты которые загружают данные) и обычные компоненты, которые их отображают.

Следовательно vuex есть смысл использовать только в контейнерах, а дальше данные прокидывать через props в обычные компоненты.